# Android XML Layout with imagebuttons in a row

Tags: android, xml, grid, android-imagebutton

Im trying to create a row of image buttons, so lets say 3 rows and 3 columns.

I keep trying to make the images all the same size but the design just messes up.

Trying to get something like this:

Image Image Image

Image Image Image

Image Image Image

Can someone help me get these in line?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="172dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_0"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: my advice would be is to use a GridView...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you dont want to use **GridView**, you can do it with `android:layout_weight` , like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, if i wanted to add text under each image without messing up the layout how would i do that, and a slight gap between each image button so it doesnt overlap?

Comment: You can replace ImagesButon(s) in my code with LinearLayout(vertical orientation) then put the ImageButton+TextView inside it. Play with the *weight* to avoid the overlap

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to arrange images with layout_ height-width parameters. As with change in screen size, orientation etc will result into messing up the layout.

Use GridView to arrange your images on screen. See the docs for gridview [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

Comment: See the docs and yes you can. See this link for example http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/07/custom-grid-view-example-in-android.html and this http://mrbool.com/implementing-gridview-in-android/27725